# docker for windows - docker push gives the message "server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed"

Tags: docker, authorization, push

I am using Docker for Windows on a windows machine.
I successfully created images using "docker pull" command

When I try to push the the image to my local repository, either by "docker push " command or by trying to push the image from the Docker for Windows GUI (choosing the image and clicking "Push"), I get the error "server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed"

I did not find much help online about this issue. I'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error was the fact the image was not tagged.

If I don't tag the image the system assumes I am trying to push the image to the common repository which I do not have permissions to, of course, not my own repository.

So I need to tag the image to the name of my private repository:

docker tag hello-world-image /hello-world-image